# If of loops or loop with if

Tags: c++, coding-style

Assuming the compiler is smart enough to only evaluate the `if` in the second example once, which version should one (semantically) use and why?

```
if (b) {
  for (auto a : as) {
    foo(a);
  }
} else {
  for (auto a : as) {
    bar(a);
  }
}
```

vs:

```
for (auto a : as) {
  if (b) {
    foo(a);
  } else {
    bar(a);
  }
}
```

I hope this question is not too opinion based.

Comment: There isn't enough information here to give an authoritative answer.  If the language were specified then, as others have noted, some other alternatives could improve readibility.  However, in its current form, this question is entirely opinion based.

Comment: @ MetaFight Fair enough, let's say it's C++11.

Comment: Which one has the lowest cyclomatic complexity?

Comment: The latter is [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)'er, so I'd prefer it.

Answer (score 5):

If the language supports it, I'd opt for:

```
f = b ? foo : bar;
for (auto a : as) {
    f(a);
}
```

This approach avoids worrying about whether the `if` is repeatedly evaluated and avoids code repetition.

Comment: Put `auto` before `f = ...` and it's valid C++11, as long as `foo` and `bar` designate a single function each, instead of an overload set, template or type.

Comment: @Deduplicator, thanks for that. When I answered the language hadn't been specified and it's been many years since I used C++, so don't know the correct syntax. If you have enough rep to edit my answer, please feel to edit it.

Answer (score 2):

Joker

```
if (b){
    f = foo;
}
else {
    f = bar;
}
for (auto a : as) {
    f(a);
}
```

Comment: `f = (b)?foo:bar;  for (auto a : as) { f(a); }`

Answer (score 1):

Not enough information is given.

The first version assumes that b is invariant over foo() and bar() for all parameters a.  The second version assumes that b is not necessarily so invariant and programs defensively.

The compiler probably has no way of knowing that b is in fact invariant over foo() and bar(), and hence cannot translate the second version into the first.  The hardware architecture may or may not allow David Arno's suggestion to be done easily.

If b is not invariant over foo() and bar(), the first version is erroneous.  If b is so invariant, the second version MAY waste a fair amount of time testing b.

```
auto c = b;  // assume invariance and force the compiler to believe it.
for (auto a : as) {
  if (c) {
    foo(a);
  } else {
    bar(a);
  }
}
```

The above assumes invariance of b and tells the compiler to assume it for the purposes of optimization.  Obviously, if b is not invariant, this is just as bad as the original first version, at a cost of higher complexity.